# Concrete implementation of dependency injected service in ASP.NET Core 3 not being called

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-identity

I read [Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) to implement Identity Services in my ASP.NET Core 3 web application. Part of the walkthrough for enabling identity services is the creation of an EmailSender class (described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)) to send account registration emails, etc. My problem is that my EmailSender implementation is never being called.

Following the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio I created my concrete EmailSender implementation:

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    public EmailSender(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    ...
}
```

then I register this service (along with the other identity related bits) in Startup.cs with the dependency injection framework:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(
                  options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
    services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);

    ...
}
```

ASP.NET Core Identity Services auto-generates code for registering, logging in, etc. and calls the email service as follows:

public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    ...
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

```
public RegisterModel(
    ...
    IEmailSender emailSender)
{
    ...
    _emailSender = emailSender;
}


 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
 {
     ...
     await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
          $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");
     ...
 }
```

Problem I'm having is that EmailSender is never instantiated. Breakpoints on all methods and constructor (even made a default constructor as a test) aren't hit.

In my debugging I see that `RegisterModel` is instantiated and `emailSender` is set.  But when F11ing through the statement that calls email sender:

```
await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");
```

the immediate next line of code is executed - no debugger hop to `EmailSender` at all.

This feels like a DI registration problem to me yet the fact that `IEmailSender.emailSender` is non-null means it sees the concrete implementation.

Comment: check the order in configureservices. maybe call emailservice after the authmessagesenderoptions? i'm thinging the password etc to it is not present when you register the emailsender before the password is available

Comment: @JohanHerstad Unfortunately no change in result.  I did make the swap and try it, but I also doublecheck Microsoft documentation and verified the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and after some head scratching, I noticed that Microsoft's implementation was "overriding" my IEmailService implementation. Solved this by deleting it from the Using statements at the top of the file.
I commented out this line:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
```

to

```
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
```

This goes for any other interface you may implement, check the using statements for any other existing implementation.